# How to bind (?) several variables in a complex way in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

Suppose some widget like range slider binds to a 2-element array. Also I want to display range limits in separate text fields. How to accomplish that?

```js
 angular
        .module('myApp', ['ui.slider']);
        
  angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('MyController', MyController);
           
    function MyController() {
      var vm = this;
        
        vm.slider = [5,15];
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/src/slider.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
        <strong>Range slider:</strong>
        <div ui-slider="{range: true}" min="1" max="20" step="1" ng-model="vm.slider"></div>
          <strong>It's value is bound as an array:</strong><br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slider" /><br>
          <strong>How to bind sepately:</strong><br>
        From: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.sliderfrom" /> To: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.sliderto" /><br>
    </div>
</body>
```

I need to update array on each limit change and reverse. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly bind with array elements

```
From: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slider[0]" />
To: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slider[1]" />
```

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ui.slider']);

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.slider = [5, 15];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/src/slider.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
    <strong>Range slider:</strong>
    <div ui-slider="{range: true}" min="1" max="20" step="1" ng-model="vm.slider"></div>
    <strong>It's value is bound as an array:</strong>
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slider" />
    <br>
    <strong>How to bind sepately:</strong>
    <br>From:
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slider[0]" />To:
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.slider[1]" />
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Array text field is not updated if upper limit text field changed, see: https://i.imgur.com/fEVwPm3.jpg

Comment: @Dims, Its due to `input` initially `vm.slider` is binded using the toString() method i.e. `[5, 15].toString()`  which will bind `5,15` later its not converted to array its plain text

Comment: So is it possible to fix?